# Textbox maxLength with nextLine issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I've set the Textbox MaxLength to 10 and I noticed that I can press *ENTER* for only 5 times, after that I can't type any characters.

I am wondering what can I do in order to *ENTER* whenever I want but at the same time restrict the number of characters by MaxLength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use MaxLength as enter is two characters
Put the restriction on the data

[Validation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

*ENTER* actually prints two characters `\r\n` thats why you can press it only 5 times

Answer (score 0):

Since an enter is #13#10, it means 2 characters are added every time. If you want to ignore enters i think you would have to write a check yourself